# How to disable test suite in pom

Tags: jenkins, soapui

I have reusable test project that include 2 test suite. For one customer test suites should be run on jenkins, for other - only one test suite. How to disable test suite in pom?

Comment: Doc are here: https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html#5-Plugin-Settings

Comment: Have you tried commenting your unwanted suite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to disable test suite in pom. The solution is to define needed test suite in pom.